# Grunt filename as variable

Tags: variables, gruntjs, filenames

Maybe my question will sound very silly, but I've searched about everywhere without finding an answer.

I have the need to stock the filename Grunt is manipulating in a variable, to be able to reuse it in other tasks.

I.e.

```js
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'tmp/output/',
      src: ['*.html'],
      dest: 'dist',
      rename: function(dest, src) {
        var d = new Date();
        var mh = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var dy = d.getDate();
        var yr = d.getFullYear();
        return dest + "/" + yr + "_" + mh + "_" + dy + "_" + src;
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

In this example i'm renaming a file attaching the date. I need to stock the resulting filename in a variable to be reused in other task and finally logged to the console.

Need some help to understand how Grunt works with files!

**EDIT:**
As suggested i've changed the paths with the real values.

What I mean is :

1. Someone put a file called `foo.html` in my folder
2. I renamed it dynamically via Grunt in ie. `2018_01_02_foo.html`
3. I need a variable that stock the completely new filename, or simply the "foo" part, but somehow make me able to reuse that name in other tasks

TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Declare a variable in the outer scope of each Task and assign an empty array to it. For example:

   ```js
   var cachedFileNames = [];
   ```
2. Then within the `rename` function of the `copy` task, store each dynamically generated filename in the `cachedDirNames` array by utilizing the [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)  method. For example:

   ```js
   cachedFileNames.push(fileName);
   ```
3. The filenames in `cachedFileNames` array can now be reused in other tasks *(As shown in the custom `logFileNames` task below)*.

---

**Gruntfile.js**

The following `Gruntfile.js` gist demonstrates points 1-3 above:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  var cachedFileNames = []; /* 1. Filenames are dynamically
                                  added via the `copy` task.*/


  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  grunt.initConfig({

    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'tmp/output/',
          src: ['*.html'],
          dest: 'dist',
          rename: function(dest, src) {
            var d = new Date();
            var mh = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var dy = d.getDate();
            var yr = d.getFullYear();
            var fileName = yr + "_" + mh + "_" + dy + "_" + src;

            cachedFileNames.push(fileName); // 2. Cache each new filename.

            return dest + "/" + fileName;
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  // 3. Custom Task to demonstrate the `cachedFileNames`
  //    array can be accessed via another task.
  grunt.registerTask('logFileNames', function() {
    cachedFileNames.forEach(function(fileName) {
      grunt.log.writeln(fileName);
    })
  })

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'copy', 'logFileNames' ]);
};
```